# How do I open any app from my web browser (Chrome) in Android, automatically?

Tags: redirect, android-intent

I am struggling a little bit. I have a common url like www.domain.com/test.html
and i want Android users to get my app open if "test" is included, otherwise if they don't have the app their should be directed to the play store. I got everything implemented and it works with mozilla browser. But using chrome on Android it should be forbidden to automatically open the app if it is available!?. Now if the user enters www.domain.com/test.html and i recognize he is using Android and Chrome i tried the intent stuff in a script in a redirected www.domain.com/android_chrome.html:

```
 <script>       window.open("intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end","_self")
   </script>
```

But the App won't open automatically. If i use a regular Link:

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

it works. But i want to let it open automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google restricted starting intents from javascript apps, that's why it isn't working. Security reasons I guess. You should just display nice big link to let user switch to your app instead of website - or let him continue if he doesn't want to launch the app.

Forcing users into using app is bad, IMO. Splash screen suggesting to use it is okay, but don't push it.

Comment: Does this also happens if i create an extra popup, which directs to the intent:// if pressed yes. In this case the user did an explicit gesture? Like: `if (confirm("Open GetVise?") == true) {
        window.open("intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end");
    } else {
        
    }
     </script>`.

Comment: Try it but it's still javascript so IMO it wouldn't work either.

Comment: I did it with a workaround avoiding using javascript. I use the .htaccess with rewrite rules instead.

Comment: Glad you found the solution! :)

Comment: I have changed my button code to the one in the example webpage: <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end" type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir Soria Bus</a>